# How can I build a schedule message function for a Facebook chat bot? I can not find any support from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

I am trying to build a chat bot which can automatically sent alert to users who subscribed to my own page. However I can not find any support from facebook messenger for this task. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately fb messenger is not an one stop shop solution yet. I'd recommend using this excellent npm module [node_schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule).I guess it should fit your needs.